# Как изменить программу по умолчанию для открытия документов типа .cs

Tags: c#, windows

Я недавно случайно поставил программу по умолчанию для открытия файлов типа cs на μTorrent.
Как мне теперь поменять эту программу на Visual Studio?

Comment: Откройте свойства любого cs файла в проводнике и выберите Visual Studio как связанное приложение.

Answer (score 5):

**Первый вариант:**

`ПКМ на файл -> Открыть с помощью -> Выбрать другое приложение`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Внизу появившегося окошка поставить галочку `Всегда использовать это приложение для открытия .cs файлов`, выбираем программу.

**Второй вариант:**

`ПКМ на файл -> Свойства -> Общие`
Вторая строка — `Приложение`. Справа кнопка `Изменить`.

---

Ну а вообще такое гуглится за пару секунд: https://serfery.ru/kompyuternaya-gramotnost/kak-zadat-programmu-po-umolchaniyu-dlya-otkrytiya-fajlov-opredelyonnogo-tipa-v-windows/

Answer (score 0):

Самый удобный вариант для ручной смены: Вызвать Свойства файла и в верхней трети окна найти кнопку Изменить, рядом с показанной ассоциацией, и выбрать приложение.